# Unable to deploy Node app on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

I am trying to deploy Node(MEAN) app on heroku from Dropbox
But getting error which is not clear to me.

Here is the Log file : -

```
Installing node modules (package.json)

       > bufferutil@1.2.1 install /tmp/build_40351018a3cb98a2c8dc0f452f6974b4/node_modules/bufferutil
       > node-gyp rebuild

       make: Entering directory `/tmp/build_40351018a3cb98a2c8dc0f452f6974b4/node_modules/bufferutil/build'
       CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
       SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil.node
       COPY Release/bufferutil.node
       make: Leaving directory `/tmp/build_40351018a3cb98a2c8dc0f452f6974b4/node_modules/bufferutil/build'

       > utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install /tmp/build_40351018a3cb98a2c8dc0f452f6974b4/node_modules/utf-8-validate
       > node-gyp rebuild

       make: Entering directory `/tmp/build_40351018a3cb98a2c8dc0f452f6974b4/node_modules/utf-8-validate/build'
       CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
       SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.node
       COPY Release/validation.node
       make: Leaving directory `/tmp/build_40351018a3cb98a2c8dc0f452f6974b4/node_modules/utf-8-validate/build'

       > bluedress@0.1.0 postinstall /tmp/build_40351018a3cb98a2c8dc0f452f6974b4
       > tsd reinstall -so

       sh: 1: tsd: not found

       npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-93-generic
       npm ERR! argv "/tmp/build_40351018a3cb98a2c8dc0f452f6974b4/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_40351018a3cb98a2c8dc0f452f6974b4/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "install" "--unsafe-perm" "--userconfig" "/tmp/build_40351018a3cb98a2c8dc0f452f6974b4/.npmrc"
       npm ERR! node v5.11.1
       npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
       npm ERR! file sh
       npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
       npm ERR! errno ENOENT
       npm ERR! syscall spawn
       npm ERR! bluedress@0.1.0 postinstall: `tsd reinstall -so`
       npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
       npm ERR!
       npm ERR! Failed at the bluedress@0.1.0 postinstall script 'tsd reinstall -so'.
       npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
       npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the bluedress package,
       npm ERR! not with npm itself.
       npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
       npm ERR!     tsd reinstall -so
       npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
       npm ERR!     npm bugs bluedress
       npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
       npm ERR!     npm owner ls bluedress
       npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

       npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/build_40351018a3cb98a2c8dc0f452f6974b4/npm-debug.log
-----> Build failed

       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

       Some possible problems:

       - Node version not specified in package.json
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
```

Unable to understand what could be the problem 
on local everything is working fine.
I added node version as well in package.json but still getting the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
sh: 1: tsd: not found
```

So you have to install tsd (https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsd)